# Click even on pie chart using dojo

Tags: dojo

I have a sliced pie chart.

I need to implement Click event on each slice to go other page.

Can any body tel me how to do this kind of clicks on the pie chart using dojo?

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used dojo. However if all you are looking for with Dojo is creating Charts, you might want to look at Google Chart Tools (http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use actions for that. Read this article (linked from the official docs): http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/27/dojo-charting-event-support-has-landed/

As always you can look at the code for standard actions in `dojox/charting/action2d`.